# Magento customize editing product page in admin panel

Tags: magento

I want to customize the editing product in admin panel for a fresh Magento installation. So here are the things I've done so far:

I looked into edit.phtml located at `app/design/adminhtml/defautl/default/template/catalog/product` and saw those line:

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getSaveUrl() ?>" method="post" id="product_edit_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey')?>
<div style="display:none"></div>
```

It seems that magento requires those lines to render the tabs in editing product page.

I looked into catalog.xml located at `app/design/adminhtml/defautl/default/layout/` and saw those line:

```
<adminhtml_catalog_product_edit>
    <update handle="editor"/>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="adminhtml/catalog_product_edit" name="product_edit"></block>
    </reference>
    <reference name="left">
        <block type="adminhtml/store_switcher" name="store_switcher" before="-"></block>
        <block type="adminhtml/catalog_product_edit_tabs" name="product_tabs"></block>
    </reference>
    <reference name="js">
        <block type="adminhtml/catalog_product_edit_js" template="catalog/product/js.phtml" name="catalog_product_js"></block>
        <block type="core/template" name="catalog.wysiwyg.js" template="catalog/wysiwyg/js.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</adminhtml_catalog_product_edit>
```

I believe the block with name = product_tabs is the source for rendering all the tabs. However I cannot find its location.

Could you tell me what's wrong here?

Comment: Have you try Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tabs  in app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Catalog\Product\Edit\Tabs.php ?